# vb.net WPF Binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection(Of MyClass)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

So, I could create an ObservableCollection(Of MyClass) and declare it is a public property. This collection would be create after I click a button. How do I go about binding a listbox control to it? These are my codes:

```
    Public Property StaticFailingPinListItem As New ObservableCollection(Of PinNameAndImageLocation)

    <ListBox Name="StaticFailingPinListBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="150" MinWidth="220" 
                                    FontSize="12" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

PinNameAndImageLocation has 2 properties: PinName & ImageLocation.
I wanted to display PinName property as item in my listbox..
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `StaticFailingPinListBox.ItemsSource=yourObservableCollection`

Comment: have you tried `ItemSource="{Binding StaticFailingPinListItem}" DisplayMemberPath="PinName"`

Comment: ^ Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare a `StaticFailingPinListItem` collection property in a `YourClass` class and implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in the class.

2) Set the `Window.DataContext` to an instance of that class:

```
DataContext = new YourClass
```

3) Bind to that property in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StaticFailingPinListItem}" ... />
```

4) Override the `ToString` method in your `PinNameAndImageLocation` class to return the `PinName` property value:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return PinName 
End Function
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: Can u pls further explain your first point? Does it mean I have to declare a collection property in my self created class instead of my main user control?

Comment: While it may not be necessary to do this for just a single property, it is customary to create a class to represent all of the data for your window or `UserControl`. The `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface is then used to notify the UI of property changes made in this class.